# How to create a List<string> C# 2.0

Tags: c#, list

```
    List<string> icons = new List<string>[]
        {
            "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
            "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
        }
```

If i try to use code from above, compiler throws a message Error "; expected",
also if i add ";" at the end of the braces everything looks fine until i try to compile the program, then i get Error for each character in the list:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

And also another error that looks like this:

"Error  17  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

I need to mention that i use visual studio 2005, and I'm thinking perhaps this could be a reason why list doesn't works, since it worked for me in the newer version of visual studio 2015.

I am aware that List should look something like one from below, but if i try to use this syntax i get even more errors, and it looks like whole code is getting messed up.

```
    List<string> icons = new List<string>()
        {
            "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
            "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
        }
```

Comment: Add a `;` at the end of the 2nd code snippet

Comment: The second generate no errors. It Just needs a `;` it has nothing to do with List syntax.

Comment: If i do so, then i get another missing ";" right at the end of the initial line. The visual studio want it to look like this:

`List<string> icons = new List<string>();`

Also few more errors like "Error 2 Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Comment: You should not put that, it should be `List<string> icons = new List<string>()` .. It should be at the end of the `{}` block.. Like this `{};`

Comment: @Adi543 check my answer for c# 2.0 version equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second syntax is correct for C# 3.0 and later (though missing the final `;`). See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h5dlZj) for a demo.

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>()
{
   "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
   "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
};
```

Note that the `()` when using a collection initialiser `{ ... }` is optional, so this could be written as:

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>
{
   "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
   "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
};
```

Your first attempt uses `[]`, which attempts to initialise an array of `List<string>`. Each item in the initialiser (e.g. `"!"`) would then be expected to be a `List<string>`.  This isn't what you intended.

**However**, you state you are using Visual Studio 2005, which shipped with the C# 2.0 compiler.  As this syntax was introduced in C# 3.0, so you won't be able to use it.  You should ideally upgrade to a later version.  The C# 2.0 equivalent syntax would be:

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>();
icons.Add("!");
icons.Add("!");
icons.Add("N");
// ...
```

Comment: @Adi543 did you read to the end? The first two examples won't work in VS 2005. VS 2015 Community Edition is free, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed to know. Now that i know this, my question should have been how to create list in C# 2.0 compiler. You helped a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;`. You should not put `;` at the end of `new List<string>()` in case you want to use the intializer list syntax:

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>()
{
    "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
    "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
};
```

> A statement can consist of a single line of code that ends in a
>   semicolon, or a series of single-line statements in a block. A
>   statement block is enclosed in {} brackets and can contain nested
>   blocks

### Collection initializers

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method. The element
>   initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object
>   initializer. By using a collection initializer you do not have to
>   specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source
>   code; the compiler adds the calls.

The following examples shows two simple collection initializers:

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

### For C# 2.0 use this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>()
        {
            "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
            "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var icons = new List<string>()
            {
                "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
                "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete the statement with the semicolon (`;`) at the end

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>()
    {
        "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
        "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a ; after closing }

```
List<string> icons = new List<string>()
    {
        "!","!","N","N",",",",","k","k",
        "b","b","v","v","w","w","z","z"
    };
```

and make sure you using

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```